# How to use android cam as security surveillance cam for live video streaming like IP Cam app

Tags: android, security, android-studio, android-camera

I wanna build an app that will use android camera video and stream it to another android phone or on the web. I don't wanna do it through my Wifi, but i want the cam streaming to be broadcast live anywhere in the world.
Can anyone help me getting an overview of the android classes or APIs that will be helpful doing this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can't stream live video from a phone directly to another phone, there are just too many possible differences between any two given devices.

To do this you will need to have a publicly accessible server, (that you have control of) running a streaming engine, such as Woza: https://www.wowza.com/products/streaming-engine The source phone sends video to the server, and the destination phone receives video from the server.

Comment: i have server.can you please tell me how to make such an app that sends video to server?

Comment: I have no experience with it, so I don't know what the quality is but: https://code.google.com/archive/p/spydroid-ipcamera/ should give you something to start with.